# How to render HTML page using an Ajax call in Django

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

I am in the scenario where I need to make an `Ajax` call and render an `HTML` page as normally done using this command

```
@csrf_exempt
def show(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Do Something

        return render(request, "index.html")
```

Ajax

```
@csrf_exempt
def show(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():

        # Do Something

        return HttpResponse()
```

I am a bit confused can anybody point me in the right direction, Thank You

Comment: I don't understand why you think there would be a difference. If you want to render a remote, then do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question... If the view is to return the same markup in both cases then the fact it's an "ajax call" is totally irrelevant. Else, please edit your question to make clear what your problem actually is.

Comment: Hello, in simple language I need to redirect a page after `Ajax` call is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to handle this in your javascript - because only there is the place to know if the ajax call was successfull. In the case of jquery this would look like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "your_ajax_url", success: function(result){
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }});
});
```